# Using Google Play location API in a seperated class?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-play-services

In the Android Developer guide, Google showed how to use the Google Play Services API in an activity class. What is the best way to offload the API calls into a separate class?

```
public class GPSresource implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private Location location; // location
private double latitude; // latitude
private double longitude; // longitude
private GoogleApiClient mGAC;
private Context mContext;
public static final String TAG = "GPSresource";

public GPSresource(Context c)
{
    mContext = c;
    try {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGAC.connect();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGAC);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

The code I wrote above does not work since onConnected is never called since this is not an activity. Is there a better way to separate the GPS services from the Main Activity or is that the only option(If so, is there a reason as to why?) Perhaps making a thread in the main activity to run in the background?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason why this shouldn't work. Do you have logging in `onConnectionFailed` and `onConnected` that show neither is being called?

Comment: Weird, It seems like it did not log the first time I ran my app. Looks like onConnected is being called, but there is a bug with the way I am making the object in my main Activity class. - I'll make this question as solved

Comment: getLatitude() returns null with this code, how do we wait for onConnected method to be called and then return value?

Answer (score 1):

`onConnected` is called, I made a mistake with reading the logs!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
public class LocationManager implements LocationListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;

public LocationManager()
   locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    Location  mobileLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (mobileLocation != null)
    {
        onLocationChanged(mobileLocation);
    }
    Location  netLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (netLocation != null)
    {
        onLocationChanged(netLocation);
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

    String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
    //Log.v(TAG, longitude);
    String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
   // Log.v(TAG, latitude);

    /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
    String cityName = null;
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                loc.getLongitude(), 1);
   // Log.e(TAG, "addr : " + addresses.toString());
        if (addresses.size() > 0)
        cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n\nMy Current City is: "  + cityName;

   Log.e(TAG, "location : " + s);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude", "disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
}


public void pause() {
    if (locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager = null;
    }
}

public void destroy() {
    if (locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager = null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid LocationManager and use Google Play Services API instead